# get the sub index in foreach loop in simpleXMLElement

Tags: php, foreach, key

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
  <item>
    <title>This is title1</title>
    <desc>This is desc1</desc>
    <image></image>
    <tudou></tudou>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>This is title2</title>
    <desc>This is desc2</desc>
    <tudou>55362137</tudou>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>This is title3</title>
    <desc>This is desc4</desc>
  </item>
</items>
```

here's my php code:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <?php
                $xml = simplexml_load_file('post.xml');
                //print_r($xml);
                foreach($xml->item as $key=>$item )
                {
                    echo <<<HTML
                    <li>
                    <div class="published">
                        <span class="day">13</span>
                        Sep 2010
                    </div>

                    <div class="summary">
                    <a href="#slide-$key">
                            <h3>$item->title</h3>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    </li>

HTML;
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

after php render the page,the `<a href="#slide-$key">` return `<a href=#slide-item>`.
I want $key get the number of which , 
so how to get ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because simpleXML structures are not normal arrays but iterators who do not have an array index.

I don't know of any other solution than keeping track manually using a variable:

```
 $index = 0;
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('post.xml');

 foreach($xml->item as $item )
   {
       ....
       $index++;
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean `$key = 0;` (`$index` would be a much better name).

Answer (score 7):

You could use `SimpleXMLElement::xpath` to return an array of the `<item>` elements, then access the array's keys as you want.

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('/items/item') as $key => $item)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK with heredocs format, you need to wrap variables in curly braces:

```
<a href="#slide-{$key}">
  <h3>{$item->title}</h3>
</a>
```

Comment: Won't fix the issue I think: `$key` is `item` when walking through an XML Element

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` like this :

```
$item = $xml->item;
$howMany = count($item);
for($i = 0; $i < $howMany; $i++){
echo <<<HTML
                    <li>
                    <div class="published">
                        <span class="day">13</span>
                        Sep 2010
                    </div>

                    <div class="summary">
                    <a href="#slide-$i">
                            <h3>$item->title</h3>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    </li>

HTML;
}
```

Comment: Where is `$item` being fetched? I don't think this method will work for an XML element

Answer (score 0):

[Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

might try

```
<a href="#slide-{$key}">
```