# Loop through an object containing an array of objects

Tags: php

I have an object that contains an array of objects that I want to loop through.  A print_r of the object looks like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [NewDataSet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Table1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [DiamondID] => 44696069
                            [ShapeTitle] => Pear
                            [Weight] => 0.300
                            [ColorTitle] => G
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [DiamondID] => 44775332
                            [ShapeTitle] => Pear
                            [Weight] => 0.300
                            [ColorTitle] => G
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [DiamondID] => 46959935
                            [ShapeTitle] => Pear
                            [Weight] => 0.340
                            [ColorTitle] => D
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

The object came from some XML that I am retrieving via a SOAP call.

I would like to loop through the "Table1" array, accessing each object.  I am doing this via:

```
foreach($rapnetresult->NewDataSet->Table1 as $itemno=>$diamond) {
  echo "<p>Item #$itemno<br>";
  echo "DiamondID: " . $diamond->DiamondID . "<br>";
  echo "ShapeTitle: " . $diamond->ShapeTitle. "<br>";
  echo "Weight: " . $diamond->Weight"</p>";
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Item #Table1
DiamondID: 44696069
ShapeTitle: Pear
Weight: 0.300

Item #Table1
DiamondID: 44775332
ShapeTitle: Pear
Weight: 0.300

Item #Table1
DiamondID: 46959935
ShapeTitle: Pear
Weight: 0.340
```

This is what I want, where I can access each object.  However I'm confused about why the $itemno variable always has the value "Table1".  I would have expected it to be the Table1 array keys, i.e.: 0, 1, 2, etc.

Can anyone please explain why I'm not getting the expected key?  And what I have to do to get the key?

Comment: Your foreach seems correct hmmm

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour with a separate test. $itemno is always the tag, rather than the index.. could be by design for some reason..

Comment: you could maintain a separate index (init to zero before the loop and ++ on each iteration)

Comment: asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915262/get-the-sub-index-in-foreach-loop-in-simplexmlelement

Comment: Many thanks Ben. I did consider using my own index but I thought that was a bit ugly, but I guess I can live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because simpleXML structures are not normal arrays but instead are iterators that do not have an array index.

The solution it to manually maintain your own index.